# How to add primary key when inserting a data in firebase android studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do i add a primary key for each user when they register in my application? Here is my current code which i have used the username as the primary key (bad practice in programming):

```
btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
            mDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            mDialog.show();

            table_user.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    //Check if the username already exists
                    if(dataSnapshot.child(username.getText().toString()).exists()){
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Username already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                        User user = new User(user_fname.getText().toString(), user_lname.getText().toString(), user_email.getText().toString(), user_pass.getText().toString());
                        table_user.child(username.getText().toString()).setValue(user);
                        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Account successfully registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }
    });
```

And the model for my user:

```
public class User {
private String FirstName;
private String LastName;
private String Email;
private String Password;

public User() {
}

public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password) {
    FirstName = firstName;
    LastName = lastName;
    Email = email;
    Password = password;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return FirstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    FirstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return LastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    LastName = lastName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return Email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    Email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return Password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    Password = password;
}
```

}

I'm just new to firebase that's why i'm getting a hard time to understand it. Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate a unique key for the new child node, use Firebase's `push()` method:

```
table_user.push().setValue(user);
```

The key generated by `push()` is statistically guaranteed to be unique, is generated on the client (so works, even if there's no internet connection), and is chronological. The only disadvantage is that they're a bit long, and thus hard to memorize. Despite that they're really the best keys for data that is essentially chronological, or which doesn't have a natural key.

One thing to consider is to use Firebase Authentication to authenticate users. If you do that, users **do** have a natural key: their so-called UID. And since they have a natural key, you should in that case store them under *that* key. So:

```
table_user.child(uidFromAuthentication).setValue(user);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I added the following code: table_user.push().setValue(user);

And then checked firebase, it generated a unique number although it seems like it doesn't terminate and keeps on inserting the same data repeatedly. What might be the problem?

Comment: The code I shared will write precisely one node. But since you have that code inside a `addValueEventListener`, writing a new user will trigger the `onDataChange` again, which will write another new node, which will trigger it again, etc. What is the purpose of the listener? Since you're adding users with a unique ID, you don't seem to have a need for it.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks